# Dump a linux process's memory to file

Tags: linux, memory, process

Is it possible to dump the current memory allocated for a process (by PID) to a file? Or read it somehow?

Comment: You can use my [proof-of-concept script](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6267/how-to-unswap-my-desktop/6271#6271) that reads [`/proc/$pid/mem`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux/6302#6302).

Comment: You might also want to read http://superuser.com/questions/236390/how-do-i-recover-a-form-in-firefox-without-installing-a-plugin and use gcore instead.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I'm not sure how you dump all the memory to a file without doing this repeatedly (if anyone knows an automated way to get gdb to do this please let me know), but the following works for any one batch of memory assuming you know the pid:

```
$ cat /proc/[pid]/maps
```

This will be in the format (example):

```
00400000-00421000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 592398                             /usr/libexec/dovecot/pop3-login
00621000-00622000 rw-p 00021000 08:01 592398                             /usr/libexec/dovecot/pop3-login
00622000-0066a000 rw-p 00622000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
3e73200000-3e7321c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 229378                         /lib64/ld-2.5.so
3e7341b000-3e7341c000 r--p 0001b000 08:01 229378                         /lib64/ld-2.5.so
```

Pick one batch of memory (so for example 00621000-00622000) then use gdb as root to attach to the process and dump that memory:

```
$ gdb --pid [pid]
(gdb) dump memory /root/output 0x00621000 0x00622000
```

Then analyse /root/output with the strings command, less you want the PuTTY all over your screen.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this in just bash/sh without gdb?

Comment: @Programming4life [gcore(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcore.1.html)

Comment: So reading /proc/<PID>/mem directly isn't an option? I get a read error if I try and open the 'file' in an editor.

Comment: The docs on kernel.org say that what `/proc/PID/maps` shows is specifically ["Memory maps to executables and library files (2.4)"](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/proc.html#process-specific-subdirectories). Is that not accurate?

Answer (score 77):

I've made a script that accomplishes this task.

The idea commes from James Lawrie's answer and this post: https://web.archive.org/web/20190921091546/http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/52375-reading-memory-other-processes-post287195.html#post287195

```
#!/bin/bash

grep rw-p /proc/$1/maps \
| sed -n 's/^\([0-9a-f]*\)-\([0-9a-f]*\) .*$/\1 \2/p' \
| while read start stop; do \
    gdb --batch --pid $1 -ex \
        "dump memory $1-$start-$stop.dump 0x$start 0x$stop"; \
done
```

put this in a file (eg. "dump-all-memory-of-pid.sh") and make it executable

usage: `./dump-all-memory-of-pid.sh [pid]`

The output is printed to files with the names: `pid-startaddress-stopaddress.dump`

Dependencies: `gdb`

Comment: Awesome! Just used it to discover which script a mysterious bash instance was running.

Comment: Why are you only grepping for and dumpying ranges with `rw-p` permissions?

Comment: @mxmlnkn That's data (`rw-p`), the other ranges are for code (`r-xp`). If you want a dump of both, then go ahead and exchange `grep` for e.g. `cat`.

Comment: This won't give a consistent picture unless you pause the process. Getting a core file would be much more appropriate.

Answer (score 53):

try

```
    gcore $pid
```

where `$pid` is the actual number of the pid; for more info see: `info gcore`

may take some time for the dump to happen, and some memory may not be readable, but is good enough... be aware also that it can create big files, I just created a 2GB file that way..

Comment: Is `gcore` dumping  a sparse file?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai use `gcore -a PID`

Answer (score 18):

Pure bash solution:

```sh
procdump() 
( 
    cat /proc/$1/maps | grep "rw-p" | awk '{print $1}' | ( IFS="-"
    while read a b; do
        dd if=/proc/$1/mem bs=$( getconf PAGESIZE ) iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes \
           skip=$(( 0x$a )) count=$(( 0x$b - 0x$a )) of="$1_mem_$a.bin"
    done )
)
```

Usage: procdump PID

for a cleaner dump filter out `*.so` memory mapped shared libraries and empty memory ranges:

```sh
procdump()
( 
    cat /proc/$1/maps | grep -Fv ".so" | grep " 0 " | awk '{print $1}' | ( IFS="-"
    while read a b; do
        dd if=/proc/$1/mem bs=$( getconf PAGESIZE ) iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes \
           skip=$(( 0x$a )) count=$(( 0x$b - 0x$a )) of="$1_mem_$a.bin"
    done )
)
```

Comment: So, from what I understand, the idea behind the cleaner dump is that only in-memory files have a size attached to the memory region in contrast to actual application memory, which has size 0 (as the size actually used size is unknown by the OS).

Comment: One issue I have with this script is that the blocksize of 1 leads to a bandwidth of unacceptably slow ~30kB/s compared to using a blocksize equal to the page size (4096 for me) for which I get ~100MB/s! See [here](https://gist.github.com/mxmlnkn/05e1cd03a4102e353d792bd17687aed3). `getconf PAGESIZE` is used to get the page size and then the addresses and counts are divided by it.

Comment: @mxmlnkn that was lazy of me, feel free to correct my answer.

Comment: Ok, will do. Note also that the count calculation is wrong because it is done with bd-ad but bd and ad are calculated only thereafter in the first bash snippet.

Answer (score 5):

I made my own program to dump the entire process memory as well, it's in C so it can be cross-compiled to Android, which is what I needed.

You can also specify IP address and tcp port. Source code [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/109068/95403).

Answer (score 3):

man proc says :

> /proc/[pid]/mem
>                 This  file  can  be used to access the pages of a process's
>   memory through open(2), read(2), and lseek(2).

Maybe it can help you

Comment: That's not sufficient, reading another process needs a combination of /proc/<pid>/{mem,*maps}, ptrace, and some signal handling to avoid hanging the target process.

Comment: @Tobu [Indeed](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux/6302#6302). I wrote a [proof-of-concept script](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6267/how-to-unswap-my-desktop/6271#6271).

Answer (score 2):

Tool to dump process to standard output, pcat/memdump:

- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/pcat.1.html
- http://www.porcupine.org/forensics/tct.html

Comment: This one is obsolete (removed at maintainer's request); I installed the old package anyway and it failed with "Input/output error; did you use GCC with another machine's header files?".

Answer (score 1):

You can now use procdump from SysInternals suite on Linux:

https://github.com/Microsoft/ProcDump-for-Linux

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dump a separate memory segment of the running process without creating huge core file (say with gcore), you can use a small tool from [here](https://github.com/Nopius/pmap-dump). 
There is also one-liner in README if you wish to dump all readable segments into separate files.