# How can I debug these runaway ruby processes?

Tags: process, ruby

Seemingly out of nowhere (I didn't make any code changes or server changes), I've got dozens of ruby processes running my server into the ground:

[alt text http://share.shpigford.com/images/ruby-20100930-142655.png](http://share.shpigford.com/images/ruby-20100930-142655.png)

How can I track down what all of those processes are attached to?

Server is running Ubuntu 8.04.2 LTS (hardy) with Passenger and Apache 2 Red Hat Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

Look in /proc/5430 for example for information about the processes. /proc/5430/fd contains symlinks to all the open files, also see [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/173999/dump-a-linux-processs-memory-to-file/174027#174027) for information how to connect to running processes and view the memory it's using. Also, and a bit more simply, `lsof | grep pid` will show open files for the process, and `ps auxf` will show a process tree.