# Obtaining the running config for dhcpd

Tags: configuration, dhcp-server, dhcpd

Is it possible to obtain the current running config for dhcpd?  I inadvertently wiped dhcpd.conf but have not yet restarted the service.   It is currently assigning the correct IPs to my test computers so it must have the correct config in memory.

Unfortunately I don't have a backup (I  know, I know) from which I can restore but I'm hoping I can somehow dump the config from memory.

I have already checked the leases file but it only contains a small fraction of what I'm looking to obtain.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit 1:** (for Michal)

`[root@router2 log]# ll /proc/26125/fd/
total 0
lrwx------. 1 root root 64 Jun 17 20:13 0 -> /dev/null
lrwx------. 1 root root 64 Jun 17 20:13 1 -> /dev/null
lrwx------. 1 root root 64 Jun 17 20:13 2 -> /dev/null
lrwx------. 1 root root 64 Jun 17 20:13 3 -> socket:[100465655]
lrwx------. 1 root root 64 Jun 17 20:13 4 -> socket:[100465662]
lrwx------. 1 root root 64 Jun 17 20:13 5 -> socket:[100465666]
l-wx------. 1 root root 64 Jun 17 20:13 6 -> /var/lib/dhcpd/dhcpd.leases
lrwx------. 1 root root 64 Jun 17 20:13 7 -> socket:[100465667]`

and

`[root@router2 log]# cp /proc/26125/fd/3 /dhcpd3.txt
cp: cannot open '/proc/26125/fd/3' for reading: No such device or address`

Comment: I've made test with memory dump of my dhcpd (using this:http://serverfault.com/a/408929/259376), unfortunately  dhcpd config is in unreadable format. It seems that dhcpd also closes the config file after startup, so (1) won't work here.

Answer (score 1):

1. `cp /proc/PID/fd/3 /tmp/recovered_file`
   Source: https://superuser.com/questions/283102/how-to-recover-deleted-file-if-it-is-still-opened-by-some-process
2. If you have had `dhcpd.conf` file at `Ext3`/`Ext4` filesystem you can try:
   `extundelete --restore-file /path/name.conf /dev/sdXY`
   Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122323/99517
3. Memory dump:
   `gcore $pid`

Comment: Formatting in comments doesn't work so nice.  Please see edit to original post.  Thanks for your ideas but they didn't work for me.